# AngularJS - ng-disabled making input box into drop-down

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-disabled

I am using AngularJS feature "ng-disabled" and here is the HTML code for my input type.

```
 <input type="text" required="required"
        ng-disabled="dummyClassification.Name != null && dummyClassification.Name != ''" class="span12"
        placeholder="Metric Short Name" id="tShortName" 
        ng-model="test.ShortName" />
```

Pretty sweet and simple! However, when when disabled (when `dummyClassification.Name ! = null` becomes true), the input box has a drop-down option on it. As you can see it does disable it but it converts a simple input box into drop-down?

What could be the reason for this?
[image]

Comment: Debug your page css styles... Anything like `input[disabled]{}`

Comment: I found out my company adds a background to the disabled inputs (which has that arrow thing). Pretty surprised by approach but alright!